# Find the interval of increase and decrease ,local extremes , inflection points of $f(x)=x^\frac{4}{3}-x^\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: calculus

Find the interval of increase and decrease ,local extremes , inflection points of $f(x)=x^\frac{4}{3}-x^\frac{1}{3}$

Since $f(x)=x^\frac{4}{3}-x^\frac{1}{3} \Rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{4}{3}x^\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}x^\frac{-1}{3}$

can any help me further steps

Comment: Solve $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: Substitute $x^{1/3}=u$ and solve $4/3u-1/3\frac{1}{u}=0$ or $4/3u^2-1/3=0$.

Comment: i got x= 1/8 and -1/8

Answer (score 0):

with $$f(x)=x^{4/3}-x^{1/3}$$ i have found:
$$f'(x)=\frac{4}{3}x^{1/3}-\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{4}{9}x^{-2/3}+\frac{2}{9}x^{-5/3}$$